# How to keep populating tableview cell's with text while images loading in background

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimage

I reading two properties (name and image) from api stored in an array. I know how to show them inside table but i don't know how to make table after displaying name move to next row not waiting for image to be loaded. I would like to image let loading in background and show it when its done.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
//when i get text move on next cell not waiting for image to be loaded
        cell.textLabel?.text = myarray[indexPath.item].name
//make this image loading in background
         cell.imageView?.image = myarray[indexPath.item].image
        return cell
    }
```

Here is picture:
[image]

Comment: Please see if [this](https://github.com/swapniljain23/Doordash/blob/master/Doordash/View/DDRestaurantTableViewCell.swift) implementation helps you understand how it can be achieved.

Comment: thank you, i will check it.